# Cancel and pull out the external hdd cable while coping a large file

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I have a Transcend 1TB external hard drive. I had 40GB free space on the drive. I started coping a large (31GB) iso file from my windows 7 pc to this hard drive. And I cancelled the copy process halfway. But it was taking so long to end the process. So I pulled out the usb cable like a idiot. Now my 40gb free space has become 9GB and I can't find the iso file in anywhere on the drive. I have checked recycle bin and deleted it. Still I can't free up the space.

I know what I did was stupid. But can any of you out there help me to get my 30GB space back? Please. :(

Comment: Run a disc check: this should find disc blocks that have been allocated without file entries which use them. It may create one or more entries in a `\FOUND.???` directory. Check the contents of any files created with a hex listing program, and delete them if you don't need them. (Note: I haven't had any disc recoveries since XP, and these were the directory names then, but they could have changed in later Windows releases - the recovery log should tell you where they are.)

Comment: So I did the check disk from the properties > tools and It showed no errors and I can't find any folder like that.

Comment: After trying many things, I did a chkdsk /f using CMD with Admin permissions and I got my 31GB back. Thanks a lot for your input. <3

Answer (score 0):

Using the command "chkdsk /f G:" using CMD with Admin permissions fixed it.

Comment: Welcome to Super User, and thanks for closing the loop on your question.  In two days, you'll be able to accept your own answer (click the checkmark next to it).  That will show that the problem has been solved and help other users with a similar problem know that there is a proven solution.